# Display full webform submission on submission page

Tags: webforms

I'm using Drupal 7 and I'm learning PHP at the same time.

I'm using the **webform module** and when users submit a webform on my site, they can see their submission answers on the submission page but **they can't see the whole webform with all the components.**

I've read the THEMING.txt file in the webform module and I've copied webform-submission.tpl.php to my theme folder and have been trying to edit it but I can't figure out the code I need to use. I think it's probably quite a simple snippet but I'm not advanced enough yet to work it out.

Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

It's the webform-confirmation.tpl.php that you'd want to edit.

There's an article here explaining exactly what you want to achieve. https://www.drupal.org/node/1515548

Comment: Thanks for the reply but maybe I should have been clearer.


My clients can only submit a webform once which means that after they have submitted it, all they can see is their submission answers. In this case, the answers on their own have no meaning without the context of the components. In other words, they need to be able to click on the results tab and see the entire webform with the answers that they submitted.

Thanks for any help :)